# How do I copy/clone a row in jqgrid?

Tags: php, jqgrid

I am trying to create a custom button in jqgrid that would allow me to clone a selected row/record. I have currently got this alert working correctly and I am able to display the record id of the selected row with the following code:

```
$buttonoptions = array("#pager",
    array("caption"=>"Clone", "title"=>"Clone selected Record", "onClickButton"=>"js: function(){
        var selr = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
        if(selr) alert(selr);
        else alert('Please select the row you want to Clone first!');
        }"
    )
);
$grid->callGridMethod("#grid", "navButtonAdd", $buttonoptions);
```

I was thinking of using the 'getRowData' and 'addRowData' to achieve this with the following code:

```
var rowData = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getRowData',selr);
jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('addRowData',0,rowData,'last');
```

used like this

```
$buttonoptions = array("#pager",
    array("caption"=>"Clone", "title"=>"Clone selected Record", "onClickButton"=>"js: function(){
        var selr = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
        if(selr)
        var rowData = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getRowData',selr);
        jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('addRowData',0,rowData,'last');
        else alert('Please select the row you want to Clone first!');
        }"
    )
);
$grid->callGridMethod("#grid", "navButtonAdd", $buttonoptions);
```

but this isn't working.

I would appreciate some help getting this resolved, as I have been trying for a while without any success and I cannot find any code examples on how to achieve this.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please explain more detailed what does not work? If you hint the button what is happen? Which version of Guriddo Suito PHP is used?

Comment: The grid simply does not come up. The version seems to be 4.3.2. Would it be worth updating the version? If I update it, would I need to adjust my code in most of the other working modules that I have coded? Thanks Tony.

Comment: If the grid does not come up, then there is a maybe somewhere error in the code, Try to isolate the problem - by example remove the code with the navButtonAdd and see if the grid come up.

Comment: This works ....   if(selr)
        var rowData = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getRowData',selr);
        // var lastid = 21;
        else alert('Please select the row you want to Clone first!');

Comment: and this doesn't ....   if(selr)
        var rowData = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getRowData',selr);
        var lastid = 21;
        else alert('Please select the row you want to Clone first!');

Comment: It seems that the moment I add another line of code after the first semicolon, the code fails. But I cannot understand why. Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks Tony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a error in if else clause - you missed { } the brackets. It should be

```
$buttonoptions = array("#pager",
    array("caption"=>"Clone", "title"=>"Clone selected Record", "onClickButton"=>"js: function(){
        var selr = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
        if(selr) { 
            var rowData = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getRowData',selr);
            jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('addRowData',0,rowData,'last');
        } else {
            alert('Please select the row you want to Clone first!');
        }
      }"
    )
);
$grid->callGridMethod("#grid", "navButtonAdd", $buttonoptions);
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Tony, that has fixed my issue. However, I now have another question. This clones a row in the Grid, but it does not save an equivalent record in the database. How do I achieve this? Even if I edit the record in the grid, adjust manually the MySQL table record id and click update, no record is actually added to the database. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Tony, thank you for all your help. I have found a way to make this work by using the $grid->setAfterCrudAction('edit', command! Thank you again for all your help.